# Metro IndexedDB, browsing the database

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, indexeddb, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to store data in a "Metro" App for Windows 8 using IndexedDB.

I would like to be able to browse the database (to monitor that my operations modify the data as intended). So my question is; Is there any way of viewing the actual database of a metro app (IE10)? (something like in Chrome Dev Tools (Resources > IndexedDB))

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know, but my [linq2indexeddb library](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com) has a viewer in it. That way you can inspect the content of you database while debugging. The nuget package for Metro apps can be found [here](https://nuget.org/packages/Linq2IndexedDBWin8). And as last, I have a [blogpost](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/linq2indexeddb-debugging-indexeddb.html) on how you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. Strange that Visual Studio (or the webdebugger i VS) doesn't have this, since it seems to be the only (sane) way of storing larger json objects clientside in Metro?

Comment: Maybe tis will be added in the future :). I think the reason they don't have it is because there is no way the retrieve the database names u are using. (At least not using JS and the API)

Answer (score 3):

The IE team has a blog post [Debugging IndexedDB Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/25/debugging-indexeddb-applications.aspx) that includes an IDBExplorer module that you can incorporate into your application (for testing, not recommended for production)

Comment: This does work, but as you can imagine, it's not a great experience. You have a pick a place to embed the iframe and style it (500x500 works okay). You'll also need to edit the version of jQuery it's using (use appendTo's version instead of pointing to a CDN).