# how to access index database data in windows 8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs, winrt-async

Our Devteam is caching some data in index db.To test some scenarios we want to access this index db and modify some of its data.Is there a way we can do this like we do it for isolated storage using isolated storage explorer tool? The application is developed using HTML5 and javascript.

Comment: this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581523/metro-indexeddb-browsing-the-database) may give lead to some solutions